# I can't convert a .png to .jpg with pillow because of transparency

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

I want to convert .png image with transparency to .jpg with PIL in python. When i use the "convert" method it says that i cant handle the alpha background.

```py
from PIL import Image
import os

i = Image.open('hi.png')
i.convert('RGB')
i.save(os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'folder to be sved to', 'hi.jpg'))
```

It should convert it to .jpg but throws this error 'OSError: cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG'

Comment: On my side, working well, Please share your image

Comment: This was introduced in Pillow 4.2.0. See https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/docs/releasenotes/4.2.0.rst#removed-deprecated-items:
"Before Pillow 4.2.0, attempting to save an RGBA image as JPEG would discard the alpha channel. From Pillow 3.4.0, a deprecation warning was shown. From Pillow 4.2.0, the deprecation warning is removed and an :py:exc:`IOError` is raised."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*convert()*](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert) returns a converted copy of the image; it doesn't change the original. You need to create and save a new image, like so:

```
i = Image.open('hi.png')
new_i = i.convert('RGB')
new_i.save(os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'folder to be sved to', 'hi.jpg'))
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! this worked perfectly